# Does $P(X>x, Y>x)= P(X>x)P(Y>y)$ implies independence?

Tags: random-variable, independence, definition

We know, by definition, that two random variables are independent if
 $$P(X\leq x, Y\leq y)= P(X\leq x)P(Y\leq y).$$
If, insted, I have that 
$$P(X>x, Y>y)= P(X>x)P(Y>y),$$
does this also imply independence between $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: I assume you mean $P(X \le x, Y \le y)$?

Comment: You currently have $P(X \le x, Y \le x)$ and same for the next expression with the inequality reversed

Comment: @CliffAB Ah! You are right. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes!**

Claim: $$P(X>x,Y>y) = P(X>x)P(Y>y) \implies P(X\le x,Y\le y) = P(X\le x)P(Y\le y)$$

Proof:

Let's start by assuming $P(X>x,Y>y) = P(X>x)P(Y>y)$. Now let's expand the right side.

$$ P(X>x)P(Y>y) = (1-P(X\le x)) (1-P(Y\le y)) $$

$$= 1- P(X\le x)-P(Y\le y)+P(X\le x)P(Y\le y)$$

Now let's expand the left side:

$$P(X>x,Y>y) =P(X>x\bigcap Y>y)$$

$$=P((X\le x \bigcup Y\le y)^C) $$

$$= 1- P(X\le x \bigcup Y\le y)$$

$$= 1-\bigg[P(X\le x) + P(Y\le y) - P(X\le x,Y\le y)\bigg] $$

$$= 1- P(X\le x) - P(Y\le y) + P(X\le x,Y\le y)$$

Let's set the sides equal and cancel terms.

$$1- P(X\le x) - P(Y\le y) + P(X\le x,Y\le y) = 1- P(X\le x)-P(Y\le y)+P(X\le x)P(Y\le y)$$

$$ \implies P(X\le x,Y\le y) = P(X\le x)P(Y\le y) $$

Answer (score 4):

Note that those two statements are equivalent. Dave's proof is great, but I would go for a simpler approach:

- $-X$ and $-Y$ are independent if, and only if, $X$ and $Y$ are indepedent.
- Apply the definition for $-X$ and $-Y$

**WARNING:** I am not sure about how tough to proof the first statement really is (probably not too much). However, from an intuitive perpective, it is reasonable to assume as true (otherwise independence sucks!). The second part is quite straight-forward.

Comment: Very good additions.

Comment: This was my first thought, but it seems like it assumes the proof I gave to be true.

Comment: @Dave You are probably right that this is not a rigorous proof. However, from an intuitive perpective, the first statement is easy to assume as true (otherwise independence sucks!) and the second part is quite easy